# regex_match cases that do & don't access deleted function

Tags: c++, stl, std

I'm trying to understand why one line of my code compiles one way and another line compiles another way.

I can't pass the direntry.path().wstring() to regex_match directly without getting an "attempting to reference a deleted function" build error.

```
const std::wstring directoryPath; // function parameter
for (auto& direntry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(directoryPath))
{
    std::wsmatch fileMatches;
    if (direntry.is_regular_file()
        // Get "attempting to reference a deleted function" on the next line
        && std::regex_match(direntry.path().wstring(), fileMatches, *m_pRegexFile)
        && fileMatches.size() >= 2)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Same thing compiles OK if I add the **filePath** variable.

```
const std::wstring directoryPath; // function parameter
for (auto& direntry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(directoryPath))
{
    std::wsmatch fileMatches;
    std::wstring filePath = direntry.path().wstring();
    if (direntry.is_regular_file()
        && std::regex_match(filePath, fileMatches, *m_pRegexFile)
        && fileMatches.size() >= 2)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Meanwhile this works just fine as-is.

```
std::wregex regexSubdirectory(L"cam.*", std::regex::icase);
for (auto& direntry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(baseFolder.c_str()))
{
    if (direntry.is_directory()
        && std::regex_match(direntry.path().wstring(), regexSubdirectory))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My code is compiling, but I don't like mysteries.  Why does one compile without the variable and the other require it?  Best I can tell, one is probably passing const CharT* under the hood, while the other is passing const std::basic_string&.  But... I am scratching my head at the definitions (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) and I *think* they should both be passing the same thing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at #7 in the list on that cppreference page.
The call that takes an rvalue `basic_string` is marked as deleted.

In your first call, you are passing a temporary string. (rvalue)

In your second call, you are passing an lvalue.

[Later]
The reason that that call is deleted is to prevent a programming error. Consider the following bit of code from your example:

```
std::regex_match(direntry.path().wstring(), fileMatches, *m_pRegexFile);
```

When this returns, `fileMatches` contains a bunch of iterators into the string that it matched against. However, the string is a temporary, and once `regex_match` returns, it will be destroyed. Now accessing any of the matches in `fileMatches` will be undefined behavior - and probably a crash.

Comment: Thanks.  I was certain I was using case (4) but I guess I'm using (7).  I don't really see the difference between the two, except the parameters are named in (4) and not in (7).  I suppose that notation is supposed to indicate lvalues vs. rvalues (?).  That is not obvious, but okay.